# Why should BLL layer use method overloads instead of separate methods with individual names...shouldn't it be the other way around?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, webforms

I don’t understand why is using method overloads( at BLL layer ) preferred over using separate methods with individual names.

For example, if our web app has at DAL layer methods *GetAllArticles, GetArticlesByCategory, GetPublishedArticles and GetPublishedArticlesByCategory* for retrieving articles from the DB, then it is recommended that at BLL layer we use *GetArticles()* overloads to call all of the above DAL methods.

a) But why is using *GetArticles* overloads preferred over using (at BLL layer) *GetAllArticles, GetArticlesByCategory, GetPublishedArticles and GetPublishedArticlesByCategory* methods ( these methods would call DAL's *GetAllArticles, GetArticlesByCategory, GetPublishedArticles and GetPublishedArticlesByCategory*, respectively )?

Namely, I realize that business objects are meant to abstract data base schema and make them more human understandable. But as far as I’m concerned, if I was UI developer, it would be far easier for me if BLL layer had methods *GetAllArticles, GetArticlesByCategory, GetPublishedArticles and GetPublishedArticlesByCategory*, instead of BLL having *GetArticles* overloads, since by just looking at the name of the method, I would know exactly what it does! Thus, aren't methods with individual names more closely to human way of thinking than overloads - which is exactly what DLL should provide

b) So are *GetArticles* overloads supposed to more intuitive than *GetAllArticles, GetArticlesByCategory, GetPublishedArticles and GetPublishedArticlesByCategory*?!

thanx

Comment: Who recommends this?  Personally, I would do it the other way - use the detailed names in the BLL and the overloads in the DAL.

Comment: The guy that replied at this link said that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488772/single-overloaded-method-at-bll-layer-vs-bll-methods-having-one-to-one-correspond/1489158#1489158 ...but I'm not 100% sure, since I'm a bit confused by the term "fewer coarse-grained methods in the BLL" ... in other words, I have no idea what that means. Also, i'm reading a book "Website programming - problem, design and solution" and the author used overloads at BLL layer and detailed names in DAL

Answer (score 0):

Either way it is fine and depends on the consumers of the layer.
You can choose overload or separate names at both layers. It all depends on the audience/user.

In case where your layers are developed as separate projects and will generate separate DLLs and these DLLs might be consumed at different places this choice become more important.